# Custom iPhone return key text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set custom return key type for `UITextField`?

```
[txtField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
```

I want to have the word "SHARE" in place of the return key type.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You get the return key and keyboard types defined in the OS. Unless you want to try to hack the keyboard's view hierarchy to change that button, which would be a really bad plan. (Standard recommendation here is to file a bug report with Apple to let them know you'd like more/different options.)