# Would it be OK to add a custom button on a system keyboard in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-4.2

I have a requirement wherein I have to change the text of the return key of the iPad to Sign-in. Obviously it is not one of the options available in the sdk. I have searched it over the net and it seems doing that possible.

The only question remaining is whether the app would be accepted by Apple  if I modify the default system keyboard? The HIG is not clear on this , it states that "**A custom input view can replace the system-provided onscreen keyboard in apps**" and "**You can also provide a custom input accessory view, which is a separate view that appears above the keyboard (or your custom input view)**". Nothing about whether we are allowed to add an extra button on a system keyboard.

Any experiences??

Comment: Have you tried your solution and did it pass the Apple's review? @Vin

Comment: @Gon we have since '11 developed many apps with custom keyboards. Designing custom input views is OK. If you don't want the system keyboard, design your own and Apple approves.However adding a button or two on the system keyboard, using hacks is still not acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get any satisfactory answer, I convinced the client that it would be inappropriate to modify the default system keyboard for a sake of one button(even if it is allowed by Apple). We are now going for the "Go" option available for return key.

Answer (score 3):

@Vin you can change the name of return key of the keyboard to your requirement. I have an app that has the changed to return key name to Done and Search. And apple did not reject it.

Comment: "Done" and @"Search" are amongst the available options for return key. I want to set it as "Sign-In".

Comment: yes you can do that too. if it is documented than you can always use it.

Comment: that is the question robin, Sign-in is nowhere present in the available options.

Answer (score 3):

To "Sign-In" you can use the return key `UIReturnKeyJoin`

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyJoin;
```

---

### EDIT

> Nope. You get the return key and
> keyboard types defined in the OS.
> Unless you want to try to hack the
> keyboard's view hierarchy to change
> that button, which would be a really
> bad plan. (Standard recommendation
> here is to file a bug report with
> Apple to let them know you'd like
> more/different options.)

see [Custom iPhone return key text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623263/509535)

Comment: actually I want "Sign-In" exactly as you are seeing it within the quotes, on the return key.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not possible to change the text. I edit my question.

Comment: I want to know whether my app would be rejected if I do that?

Comment: Hmm, I have no experience if Apple reject an app with hacked keyboard. Just test it! If Apple reject your app, you can exlain it to your customer and use the UIReturnKeyJoin. You have nothing to lose :)